# Php Code Breaks Background and Tables

Tags: php

The code below breaks my page... no wallpaper or tables are shown. The only thing shows is the logo and the login form. The form suppose to log me in then show my account name and some numbers.How to fix the below code?

```
    <?php

   include 'wasudf.php';

   //
   // get session id
   //
   $SessionID = $_GET['SessionID'];

   if (!$SessionID)
      $SessionID = $_POST['SessionID'];

   if (!$SessionID)
       $SessionID = $_COOKIE['SessionID'];

   if (!$Function)
      $Function = $_GET['FunkShun'];

   if (!$Function)
      $Function = $_POST['FunkShun'];

   if (!$Function)
      $Function="Home";

   if (!$SessionID)
      {

echo'     <form action="index.php" method="post" id="LoginForm" style="color:#FFF">';
echo'     <input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="new"></input>';
echo'     Username:';
echo'     <label>';
echo'     <input type="text" name="AccountNo" value="" class="input" size="28"></input>';
echo'     </label>';
echo'     <BR /><BR />';
echo'     &nbsp;&nbsp;Password:';
echo'    <label>';
echo'    <input type="password" name="Password" value="" class="input" size="30"></input>';
echo'    </label>';
echo'     <BR /><BR />';
echo'    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/input-img.gif" value="Log On" class="input-img"></input>';
echo'    <BR /><br />';
echo'    <a href="#" class="link" style="font-size:12px;">Register now!</a>   <a href="#" style="font-size:12px;">Forgotten your password?</a> ';
echo'    </form>';

return;
      }

   //
   // this is a new session - add to web session table
   //
   if ($SessionID == "new")
      {
      $AccountNo = check_input(strtoupper(trim($_POST['AccountNo'])));
      $Password = check_input(strtoupper(trim($_POST['Password'])));

      if (!$AccountNo)
         ExitLogOn("Invalid Account/Password");

      $rs=mysql_query("select * from accounts where code='$AccountNo' and password='$Password'",$db);
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

      if (!$row)
         ExitLogOn("Invalid Account/Password!");

      mysql_query("update system set nextsession = nextsession + 1",$db);

      $rs=mysql_query("select * from system",$db);
      $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

      $SessionID = $row['nextsession'];

      //
      // ensure this session does not exist already
      // also remove any sessions belonging to this account
      //    - ie account can only be logged on one workstation at any time
      //
      mysql_query("delete from websession where sessionid='$SessionID' or account='$AccountNo'",$db);

      $Expiry=strtotime("+1 hour");

      $xCommand = "insert into websession set ";
      $xCommand = $xCommand . "sessionid='$SessionID',";
      $xCommand = $xCommand . "ipaddress='" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "',";
      $xCommand = $xCommand . "account='$AccountNo',";
      $xCommand = $xCommand . "password='$Password',";
      $xCommand = $xCommand . "date='" . date('YmdHis',$Expiry) . "'";

      mysql_query($xCommand,$db);
      }

   $rs=mysql_query("select * from websession where sessionid='$SessionID'",$db);
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

   if (!$row)
      {
      mysql_query("delete from websession where sessionid='$SessionID'",$db);
      mysql_query("delete from elist where code='$SessionID'",$db);
      ExitLogOn("Session Expired");
      }

   if ($row['date'] < date('YmdHis'))
      {
      mysql_query("delete from websession where sessionid='$SessionID'",$db);
      mysql_query("delete from elist where code='$SessionID'",$db);
      ExitLogOn("Session Expired!!");
      }

   $Expiry=strtotime("+1 hour");

   $xCommand = "update websession set ";
   $xCommand = $xCommand . "date='" . date('YmdHis',$Expiry) . "'";
   $xCommand = $xCommand . "where sessionid='$SessionID'";

   mysql_query($xCommand,$db);

   $AccountNo = $row['account'];
   $Password = $row['password'];
   $MiscData = $row['data'];

   $rs=mysql_query("select * from accounts where code='$AccountNo' and password='$Password'",$db);
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

   if (!$row)
      ExitLogOn("Invalid Account/Password!!");

   $Name = trim($row['name']);
   $Balance = $row['balance'];

      if ($Function == "Home")
      {
      echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '" method="post">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="SessionID" value="' . $SessionID . '"></input>';
      echo '<table width=800 align=center>';

      echo '   <tr>';
      echo '      <td align=center colspan="4" style="color:#F93;">';
      echo           $Name;
      echo '      </td>';
      echo '   </tr>';

      echo '   <tr>';
      echo '      <td align=center colspan="4" style="color:#F93;">';
      echo '         Current Balance $ ' . snumber($Balance,10);
      echo '      </td>';
      echo '   </tr>';

      echo '   <tr>';
      echo '      <td align=center colspan="4">';
      echo '         &nbsp';
      echo '      </td>';
      echo '   </tr>';

      echo '</table>';
      echo '</form>';
      }

?>
```

Comment: how can i correct this without changing the above coding?

Comment: You probably have some HTML error, like a non closing tag for instance. You could use a validator http://validator.w3.org/ to check your generated HTML code. There is no way we will be able to help you with just a dump of code and no explanations.

Comment: 1) How do you expect us to know what is wrong if you provide no information other than "It is not working". 2) Don't use `mysql` functions

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also use "normal" indentation to make your code readable.

Comment: Also dont build html in php string variables like that if youre outputting them directly. Switching in an out od php is much easier to read, maintain and debug.

Comment: @DashawnThompson you can't. you need to change the coding. Is that an option?

Comment: Yeah i can change the coding, thats no problem.

Comment: Im a newbie sorry everyone :( be easy on me please. The code was created and i designed a site around the code. Thanks to everyone that replied, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using both `GET` and `POST` on the same page.

```
$SessionID = $_GET['SessionID'];

if (!$SessionID)
  $SessionID = $_POST['SessionID'];

if (!$SessionID)
   $SessionID = $_COOKIE['SessionID'];

if (!$Function)
  $Function = $_GET['FunkShun'];

if (!$Function)
  $Function = $_POST['FunkShun'];
```

And what's with all the reassigning of `$Function`?

Comment: im a newbie sorry everyone :( be easy on me please. The code was created and i designed a site around the code.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that replied, your help is most appreciated.